# Babel uses the wrong font for roman math

Tags: fonts, babel, hebrew

I use `babel` with `lualatex` to write documents in our native language Hebrew, and I encountered a strange issue. Despite the fact I defined a custom font for **Hebrew only**, when I use roman style in math mode, for example, `\mathrm{kg}`, it uses the Hebrew font instead of the default English font:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Calibri}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Calibri}

\begin{document}
\[ kg \qquad \mathrm{kg} \]
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]
and I want to use the default English font for math expressions. Commenting out the `babel` setup (since this example doesn't involve any Hebrew) gives the desired result:

[image]

Notice that regular italic math is unaffected and rendered correctly in both cases.
How can I configure `babel` to use the default fonts for English, especially in math mode (I don't want any Hebrew involved in math most of the time)?

Comment: add `no-math` to the class deceleration options, e.g.  `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, no-math]{extarticle}`.

Comment: @UdiFogiel This indeed solves it, but I found that this option belongs to the `fontspec` package so doing `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` is a more correct solution in my opinion. If you could explain the reason behind this behavior, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from section 3.2 of fontspec's manual

> By default, fontspec adjusts LaTeX’s default maths setup in order to maintain the correct Com-
> puter Modern symbols when the roman font changes. However, it will attempt to avoid doing
> this if another maths font package is loaded (such as mathpazo or the unicode-math package).
> If you find that fontspec is incorrectly changing the maths font when it shouldn’t be,
> apply the no-math package option to manually suppress its behaviour here.

When the command `\babelfont` is used, `babel` loads `fontspec`, hence the changes in the font.

So, as documented, you can either load package for math fonts, or pass the `no-math` option to `fontspec` to suppress such changes.

Since `fontspec` is loaded implicitly by `babel`, you will have to pass the `no-math` option from the `\documentclass` deceleration, oror by adding the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` before the first use of `\babelfont`, as you suggested.